# Salesforce Marketing Cloud Contacts Configuration ContactID Mapping

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact, contactbuilder

I would like to understand the pros and cons as well as use cases for the [Salesforce Marketing Cloud Contacts Configuration ContactID Mapping](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cab_configure_contacts.htm&type=5)

Especially for this part:  "Unless you plan to link this value only to data extracted directly from the Marketing Cloud, leave this setting disabled."

Appreciated for your helps and insight. Thank you